# Getting list of items in a div using beautiful soup

Tags: html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to use beautiful soup to pull a list of courses from a [website](https://www.udacity.com/courses/all?price=Free) but have little success. I have attached the HTML structure of the website below. I am trying to pull the list of elements from <ul class="catalog-v2_results__1FjDi"> class. The below code returns nothing. I have very little familiarity with HTML and trying to find the easiest way of doing this.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = requests.get("https://www.udacity.com/courses/all?price=Free",verify=False)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
ls=soup.find_all('ul', {'class': 'catalog-v2_results__1FjDi'})
print(ls)
```

[image: HTML Structure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The webpage is dynamic and bs4 can't render JavaScript but can mimic using bs4 with selenium. I use CSS selectors to parse the html DOM elements.

**Example:**

```
import time
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))#,options=options
data=[]  
driver.get('https://www.udacity.com/courses/all?price=Free')
time.sleep(5)
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(3)
 
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
    
for course in soup.select('.catalog-v2_results__1FjDi > li'):
    title= course.select_one('.card_title__35G97').text
    data.append({
        'title':title
        })
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
                        title
0                   Intro to Data Analysis
1                    SQL for Data Analysis
2       Database Systems Concepts & Design
3          Intro to Inferential Statistics
4                                    Spark
..                                     ...
186               Front-End Interview Prep
187              Full-Stack Interview Prep
188  Data Structures & Algorithms in Swift
189                     iOS Interview Prep
190                      VR Interview Prep

[191 rows x 1 columns]
```